# Yii apply selected class on menus

Tags: yii

I have Custom Menu links in yii project, I want to apply selected class on menus.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $serverPath.CController::createUrl('user/index'); ?>" Dashboard</a></li>
```

Any Suggestion please, I know little bit about CActive Menu but not these of types menu.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, why don't u put `<li class="selected">...</li>` if you don't want to use CMenu?!

Comment: Just add it to the <li> element.

Comment: Thanks, but there are 5 <li> and in one time only one <li> should be selected.    
I am using this method, how I can use this method on controller action.
`<?php if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'User/'){echo 'class="active"';} else { echo '';} ?>`

Comment: Thanks I solve this some little bit not complete, Use this code.

`<li><a href="<?php echo $serverPath.CController::createUrl('User/update'); ?>"
   <?php if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'User' && Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'update'){echo 'class="active"';} else { echo '';} ?> >Update</a> </li>  
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using This on all menus.I resolved some little bit my issue.

```
 <li <?php if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'any-controllery-nmae' && Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'any-function'){echo 'class="active"';} else { echo '';} ?>>
  <a href="<?php echo $serverPath.CController::createUrl('any-controllery-nmae/any-function'); ?>" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>         
 </li>

   <li <?php if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'any-controllery-nmae' && Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'any-function'){echo 'class="active"';} else { echo '';} ?>>
  <a href="<?php echo $serverPath.CController::createUrl('any-controllery-nmae/any-function'); ?>" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>         
 </li>   

    <li <?php if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'any-controllery-nmae' && Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'any-function'){echo 'class="active"';} else { echo '';} ?>>
  <a href="<?php echo $serverPath.CController::createUrl('any-controllery-nmae/any-function'); ?>" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>         
 </li>
```